# If/Else inside JQuery Accordion script - Pls check syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I'm muddling my way through Javascript and could use experienced eyes on a bit of code. I'm trying to show/hide a div depending upon the open/close state of one of my accordion divs. I'm sure my code is an unholy mess so I'm posting here because I can't seem to straighten it out (I've been at it for a couple of days so it's not from lack of trying).
Here's my script:

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                autoHeight: false,
                alwaysOpen: false,
                active: false
            });
        $("h3#bubble").on("click", function(event, ui) {                
            if ("section#bubble").css(display","none") {
              $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "0"); }
            else ("section#bubble").css(display","block") {
              $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "1"); }
            });
        </script>
```

In case you're wondering, the contents of #bd4-5 is a Spotify iframe that seems to need to be outside of the accordion to load completely on page load. So I'm resorting to this opacity trickery here to handle showing and hiding.

Thank you so much to anyone who takes the time to respond.

Comment: you are missing something in css(display"
it should be css("display" ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your code:

```
if ("section#bubble").css(display","none") {
```

The `if` statement's condition needs to be surrounded by parentheses. Plus you're missing the `$` and the opening quote just before `display`. Fixing those problems gives this:

```
 if ( $("section#bubble").css("display","none") ) {
```

...but that will *set* the `display` property and evaluate as truthy; I think you are trying to *test* the `display` property so you need this:

```
if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "none") {
```

Then you have a similar problem on the `else` line:

```
else ("section#bubble").css(display","block") {
```

I think you mean `else if`, because a `else` (without the `if`) can't have a condition. Again you are missing the `$` to call the jQuery function, the opening quote before `display` and you are probably tring to test the current value of `display` rather than set it. And you need parentheses around the condition:

```
else if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "block") {
```

Your code is also missing the final `});` to close the document ready handler.

Here is my best guess at what you're trying to do:

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            alwaysOpen: false,
            active: false
        });
        $("h3#bubble").on("click", function(event, ui) {                
            if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "none") {
               $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "0");
            } else if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "block") {
               $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "1");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you all for teaching me. That's the hurdle when combing through the stack -- understanding WHY things work so you know how to use them. These answers didn't work immediately but that's likely because some other script is off but now I know why and how to set this one up. I guess it pays to step away -- there were some dumb mistakes in there that I couldn't see after all the hours hammering at this. Again, thanks for your time looking at this. It's enormously helpful.

Comment: If the css for the element I'm trying to show/hide (#bg4-5) is set to opacity:0 on page load, then the click triggers it to show just as planned. It does not, however, hide when the h3 is clicked to close the accordion. *sigh*

Comment: I'm thinking that when the click happens, the div is, in actuality, open. It hides AFTER the click. Any other thoughts on achieving this seemingly simple trick that's taken days of my life at this point?  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `"` in `display"`,  `$/jQuery` for `("section#bubble")`, `})` for closing the `$(function(){`,  `()` for `if` statement and also `else` doesn't accept a condition, you should use `else if` instead. which is unnecessary in this case. However even by using correct syntax your code doesn't do what you expect, you can use `is(':hidden')` or css method as a getter, `$('section.bubble').css('display') ==== 'block'`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        alwaysOpen: false,
        active: false
    });
    $("h3.bubble").on("click", function(event, ui) {
        if ( $('section.bubble').is(':hidden') ) {
              $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "0");
        } else {
            $('section.bubble').css("opacity", "1");
        }
    });
})
```

Note that IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Put this code before the </body> tag -->
<script>
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            alwaysOpen: false,
            active: false
        });
        $("h3#bubble").on("click", function(event, ui) {
            $("#bg4-5").toggle();
        });
</script>
```

This should do the same thing as long as all you want to do is toggle the #bg4-5 content on and off when h3#bubble is clicked.  You can only have 1 element with the id of bubble, so if you need more than one you would use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your excellent instruction, I understood enough to figure out what was going on and also what was needed! Here's what I came up with. It's clunky but it does the job!

```
            $("h3#bubbleh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
                setTimeout(function() {            
                    if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "none") {
                       $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "0");
                    } else if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "block") {
                       $("#bg4-5").css("opacity", "1");
                    }
                }, 500);
            });
```

Thanks again everyone.